# How do I make a refresh button that refresh every user's input on form minutes

Tags: c#

I have a code that read in a richtextbox the last row from a txt file.
What I want to introduce now is a refresh button with something like a text box.
I want to put it so user can put the number on the form that means minutes for the code and then user press the button refresh and the program will refresh every ... minutes. The program just call last file opened with open file dialog, refresh it on richtextbox every ... minutes.

Here is what I did to refresh just when you press the button refresh (maybe for implement it as I want I should put on the form another button and a text box?):

```
    private string thePath;
    public async void OpenFileBtn_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text File|*.txt", Multiselect = false })
         {

             if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             {
                    thePath = ofd.FileName;
                    Refresh();
             }
         }
    }




    private void Refresh()
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(thePath))
        {
            string[] lines = rd.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            ReaderRichTxtBox.Text = lines[lines.Length - 1];
        }
    }

    private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
```

How should the code be?
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some kind of Timer.
For example, you can declare a private System.Windows.Forms.Timer refreshtimer and instatiate it at the button click. 
Assuming the textbox name is TextBox1, the code should look like this:

```
 private System.Windows.Forms.Timer refreshtimer;
 private string thePath;
    public async void OpenFileBtn_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text File|*.txt", Multiselect = false })
         {

             if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             {
                    thePath = ofd.FileName;
                    Refresh();
             }
         }
    }




    private void Refresh()
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(thePath))
        {
            string[] lines = rd.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            ReaderRichTxtBox.Text = lines[lines.Length - 1];
        }
    }

    private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            refreshtimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            refreshtimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            refreshtimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) * 60000; //60000 is one minute
            refreshtimer.Start();
    }
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                   Refresh();
        }
```

At the refresh button click I set the interval to the value of the TextBox (the interval is set in miliseconds, that is why I have multiplied by 60000).
I suggest you put the intialization of the timer in the constructor of the class.
Ask me more if you have any question and I will edit my answer.

Comment: What do you mean with "I suggest you put the intialization of the timer in the constructor of the class"?
Should i put a timer in my form and call it timer1?

Comment: Did you try the code as is? The suggestion was only for better management but it should work without it.

Comment: The constructor is the method where you have InitalizeComponent() method. It has the same name as the class and is automatically initiated.

Comment: I tried it like you wrote, it don't give me error, but it don't refresh

Comment: Look I posted the code, just changed some names.
I created a text box and called it refreshertimertxtbox and then i created another refresh button called refreshtimerbtn where I wrote the code you said.

Comment: I have modified a typo error - refreshtimer.Start() instead of timer1.Start(). Check the edit of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class TextReaderForm : Form
{

    public TextReaderForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer refreshtimer;
    private string thePath;
    public async void OpenFileBtn_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text File|*.txt", Multiselect = false })
         {

             if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             {
                //using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
                {
                    //ReaderRichTxtBox.Text = await rd.ReadToEndAsync();
                    //string[] lines = rd.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    //ReaderRichTxtBox.Text = lines[lines.Length - 1];
                    thePath = ofd.FileName;
                    Refresh();
                }
             }
         }
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(thePath))
        {
            string[] lines = rd.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            ReaderRichTxtBox.Text = lines[lines.Length - 1];
        }
    }

    private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }

    private void RefreshTimerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refreshtimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        refreshtimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        refreshtimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(RefreshTimerTxtBox.Text) * 60000; //60000 is one minute
        timer1.Start();
    }
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
}
```